# Update form data based on a method in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using VueJS and I have a form with two fields. The user is required to enter the first field, and I want the value of second field to be calculated using the value from first field and passing it through a method.

**HTML**

```
<div id="app">
    <input type="text" v-model="value.label">
    <input type="text" v-model="value.slug"> 
  <!-- Slug value to display here -->
  <br /><br />
  {{value}}
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
new Vue({
    el:'#app',
    data:{
        value:{
            label: '',
            slug: ''    // This value is calculated by passing label to santiize()
        }
    },
    computed: {
    },
  methods: {
   sanitize (label) {
    return label+'something'
   }
  }
});
```

1. The user enters the first field which updates value.label
2. We need to pass value.label through sanitize() method and update value.slug . This should also immediately show up in the form field.I don't know how to do it. So, if the user types nothing in the form field it will have an automatic value returned as described.
3. Along with that it would have been awesome, if we allow the user to bypass what the santize function returns, if the user decides to type the slug value himself in the form field. So, if the user decides to type, the typed value will be set.

I created this fiddle for it - https://jsfiddle.net/9z61hvx0/8/

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by changing the data structure a bit and adding a watcher to 'label...

```
new Vue({
    el:'#app',
    data:{
        label:'',
    slug: ''
    },
    computed: {
    computedSlug () {
    return this.value.label+'Manish'
    }
    },
  watch: {
    label: function () {
        this.slug = this.sanitize(this.label)
    }
  },
  methods: {
   sanitize (label) {
    return label+'something'
   }
  }
});
```

Any other more sophesticated answers are most welcome :)

Comment: `watch` is pretty expensive and for simple scenarios as this you should use `computed` properties. all you have to do is replace 'watch' with 'computed' and return the function with computed value and use this function instead of data property in your template. for details https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html